# Is there a way to display s3 buckets in a web browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been looking for a way to get bucket list just by using a browser

Something like

```
https://AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE:wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY@s3.amazonaws.com
```

I know there are gui scripts like CyberDuck and S3browser

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: What information are you wanting to display? Would this be for public access, or only authenticated access (and how would you do the authentication)?

Comment: just buckets names(only authenticated).

Answer (score 0):

Yes using a third party tool like [Filestash](https://www.filestash.app/aws-s3-explorer.html). There's 2 approaches:

1. setup some access which you can share with the world and create a URL like this: https://demo.filestash.app/login?type=s3&access_key_id=Q3AM3UQ867SPQQA43P2F&secret_access_key=zuf%2BtfteSlswRu7BJ86wekitnifILbZam1KYY3TG&region=us-east-2&encryption_key=&endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.minio.io%3A9000%2F
2. connect to s3 from Filestash and create a read only link which will give you a link like this: https://demo.filestash.app/s/stackoverflow